# Phonegap Contacts Sort order

Tags: sorting, cordova, contacts

I'm fetching all the contacts from the device using the code from phonegap api (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html)

I'm trying to work out how to sort the contacts alphabetically.  There are some questions already on here about it but they don't have full and comprehensive answers.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var cSort = function(a, b) 
{
  aName = a.lastName + ' ' + a.firstName;
  bName = b.lastName + ' ' + b.firstName;
  return aName < bName ? -1 : (aName == bName ? 0 : 1);
 };

function contactSuccess(contacts) {
 contacts = contacts.sort(cSort);
  ...
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

The cSort function needs to reference the [correct object](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#contactname) (eg a.name.familyName), like this:

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    var cSort = function(a, b) {
        aName = a.name.familyName + ' ' + a.name.givenName;
        bName = b.name.familyName + ' ' + a.name.givenName;
        return aName < bName ? -1 : (aName == bName ? 0 : 1);
    };
     contacts = contacts.sort(cSort);  
        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
          var contact = contacts[i];                          
          $scope.phoneContacts.push(contact);
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an efficient method (that i'm using). 
1. contact.name.formatted property is rather more reliable.
2. The contacts names are grouped together, irregardless of the letter's case

```
var cSort=function(a,b){ 
        var an=a.name.formatted.toUpperCase();
        var bn=b.name.formatted.toUpperCase();
        return (an<bn)?-1:(an==bn)?0:1;
    };

function contactSuccess(contacts) {
  contacts = contacts.sort(cSort);
  ...
};
```